# How to solve 5-10 letter anagrams (without a computer or electronics)?

Tags: anagram

How can I solve 5-10 letter anagrams without a computer or electronics?

I was playing the Word Scramble category in the game *Quiz Up*  and found it complicated, only in some parts. At home, I used an anagram solver, but elsewhere my friends have aced me in this section.

I searched on the internet and found [this](http://www.wikihow.com/Solve-Anagrams-Effectively), but it requires either buying something, time, effort, or memorizing anagrams beforehand.

Comment: Generally what I do is look for pronounceable combinations and try to work from there.

Comment: I see, but what if A.) You get the correct answer, but pronounce it wrong, thinking it is the wrong answer or B.) Just can't think of anything?

Comment: Isn't any solution going to take effort?

Comment: @WendiKidd I probably should have said **the least effort**.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

- Look for patterns, such as `ing`, `tion`, `re`/`er`, `de`/`ed`, `qu`, `est`, `un`, `th`, etc.

  - Remove the letters in these patterns first, then see if you can use the prefix/suffix with the remaining letters. (If you can't, then try another prefix/suffix. Some words just don't have prefixes/suffixes, though.)
- Look at only the consonants, since th hmn brn cn stll ndrstnd mst wrds wtht vwls.
- Try compound words too (i.e. `nodbkoro` -> `knob doro` -> `knob door` -> `doorknob`).
- If all else fails, consider each letter individually as the first letter of the word, and then quickly scan the letters for the last letter. The hamun biran is aslo sirpulgrisny good at rindaeg wdros wtih tiehr frist and lsat lteetr itnact.